# Split URL in two parts (strings)

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to find a way to easily split a path (Raw URL) in two portions:
For example: /search/criteria/newyork/list

I would like to populate a string that would contain everything before third slash, in this case: "/search/criteria"
I also want to get the second portion into a string: "newyork/list"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IndexOf` to find the third slash (assuming that the first character is always the first slash, and that there are at least three slashes in the string):

```
Dim index3 = url.IndexOf("/"c, url.IndexOf("/"c, 1) + 1)
```

Then you can use `Substring` to get the parts before and after that slash:

```
Dim path As String = url.Substring(0, index3)
Dim resource As String = url.Substring(index3 + 1)
```

Comment: Guffa. Thanks. Question for you: Is there an easy way to adapt your code so it won't tank when the URL doesn't have anything after the third slash, for example: "/search/criteria" only

Comment: @MarkMarina: If it has the third slash, then it works even if the part after it is empty, giving an empty string in `resource`. If it doesn't have the third slash, then `index3` will be `-1`, so you can check for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim sAux() As String = sURL.Split("/"c)
Dim sResult As String = ""

If sAux.Length > 3 Then
    For i As Integer = 2 to sAux.Length - 1
        sResult &= sAux(i) & "/"
    Next
End If
```

Or this:

```
Dim sAux As New List(Of String)(sURL.Split("/"c))
sAux.RemoveRange(0,2)    

sResult = String.Join("/", sAux.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dim ar As String()
        Dim str1 As String
        Dim str2 As String
        Dim a As Integer
        Dim splitPosition = 3
        Dim urlToSplit = "/search/criteria/newyork/list"
        ar = urlToSplit.Split("/"c)

        If UBound(ar) < splitPosition Then
            ' there are 3 or less slashes. do what you want here, error or just exit
        Else
            For a = 0 To splitPosition - 1
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ar(a)) Then str1 += ar(a) + "/"
            Next
            For a = splitPosition To UBound(ar)
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ar(a)) Then str2 += ar(a) + "/"
            Next
        End If
```

`str1` will contain `/search/criteria/`
`str2` will contain `newyork/list/`

This code will handle any number of `/` combinations and should not error out for a badly formed Url

Answer (score 0):

If your string is always in the same format and has same number of elements (in splited array), you could use `String.Format` method as;

```
Dim arr() As String =  "/search/criteria/newyork/list".Split("/"c)
Dim str1 As String = String.Format("/{1}/{2}", arr) '/search/criteria
Dim str2 As String = String.Format("{3}/{4}", arr) 'newyork/list
```